# Wagtail CMS, Adding a gif to prodserver

Tags: heroku, homebrew, gif, wagtail

Currently, I'm trying to add an animated GIF to my Wagtail site, I have found the docs that say to `pip install wand`, and `brew install ImageMagick`:

https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.2/guide/install.html

I'm able to run it in `localhost:8000` without any problem, but when I upload it to my prod server it 500 crashes. The problem is that the prod server doesn't install ImageMagick via brew, is it any possibility to add a brew install to my pipfile or dockerfile? Using Heroku to host the server.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), ***read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)***, and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular, your current question is a bit too broad; and may remain unanswered because of that (or even gets closed). It's much better to ask a specific question based on your own solution attempt; should you get stuck somewhere specific.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Here's a link to a buildpack for Heroku to install ImageMagick on your server:
https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/duckyteam/heroku-buildpack-imagemagick

Good luck!